# Why are my Google Adsense ads not showing?

Tags: adsense

I have a network of travel guide websites where I recently added Google Adsense. I see impressions registered for the ads, but I have accessed the sites on mobile phones, laptops and desktops and have yet to manage to see the ads myself.

Can you see Adsense ads on these sites? If yes, any idea why I can't? If no, any idea on what is wrong?

[www.tokyo.vn](http://www.tokyo.vn)
[www.hanquoc.vn](http://www.hanquoc.vn)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry all, just found out that Vietnamese is not a supported language even though Vietnam is one of the 15 most populous countries in the world.